# Unexpexted Archive.php show posts instead of archive-{Custom Post Type}

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

I have created my Post Type, but I dont know what I have done wrong that archive.php shows all posts instead of archive-gallery.php. Here is the code.

**custom-post-types.php**

```
/*******            *******/
// Custom Post Type - gallery
function register_post_gallery() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => __( 'gallery', '_tk' ),
    'singular_name'      => __( 'gallery', '_tk' ),
    'add_new'            => __( 'Dodaj nową', '_tk' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Dodaj nową galerię', '_tk' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edytuj', '_tk' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'Nowa', '_tk' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Wszystkie', '_tk' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'Zobacz', '_tk' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Szukaj', '_tk' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'Nie zneleziono żadnej', '_tk' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nie zneleziono żadnej w koszu', '_tk' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => __( 'Galeria', '_tk' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'supports'          => array( 'title', 'page-attributes', 'revisions', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies'        => array( 'gallery_category' ),
    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive'       => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'gallery','with_front' => false),
    'menu_position'     => 6,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-admin-multisite'
  );
  register_post_type( 'galllery', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_gallery' );

/* gallery taxonomies */
function add_gallery_category() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => __( 'Kategorie galerii', '_tk' ),
    'singular_name'     => __( 'Kategoria galerii', '_tk' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Szukaj kategorii', '_tk' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'Wszystkie kategorie', '_tk' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Kategoria nadrzędna', '_tk' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Kategoria nadrzędna:', '_tk' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edytuj kategorię', '_tk' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Aktualizuj kategorię', '_tk' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Dodaj nową kategorię', '_tk' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nowa kategoria', '_tk' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Kategorie galerii', '_tk' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'kategorie-galerii' )
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'gallery_category', 'gallery', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_gallery_category', 0 );
```

**Here are my files inside the theme:**

[image: files]

What the file plugin shows me that the page is displayed by archive.php

[image: wtf]

Could you please help me to solve this ? I was trying to notice where is the issue but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your gallery when you register it:

```
register_post_type( 'galllery', $args );
```

Change it to `gallery` instead of `galllery`.

Comment: I have to take a rest^^. Unbelievable that I did not noticed that. I was looking for more serious issue in the code.

Thanks. Now it is working well.

Comment: @PawełStanecki No problem :)